# Are those two WWAN slots on the Latitude E6440?

Tags: ssd, installation, motherboard, dell-latitude, wwan

I am researching trying to install an extra SSD on a Latitude E6440, and there seems to be another slot labeled WWAN beneath the slot that's used everywhere I see.

Is that another identical slot? Can I use them both together, and do they both work with an SSD?

This is the slot I see used for this procedure:

[image]

This picture shows the other slot underneath:

[image]

Comment: Page 16: https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/latitude-e6440-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: Page 16 shows the WLAN card, which is different. Page 17 is unhelpful.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Latitude-E6440-mSATA-support/td-p/4355792 - just doing some googling for you.

Comment: Trust me I had been googling before asking, also I scoured the Dell website but never stumbled upon that forum post.
From what the guy said, the lower slot only works with a network card and the upper one is normal mSATA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there are 2 WWAN slots?  1 is for a cellular Internet Card. Fairly common on some Lenovo machines.

That will not be the same (at all) as an SSD slot.

Comment: The upper one is called WWAN in the Dell [guide](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124676/latitude-e6440-removal-guide-for-memory-wifi-card-wwan-card-and-coin-cell-battery). The lower one I haven't seen mentioned anywhere.

Comment: That slot is for a cellular Internet card as I mentioned.

Comment: Not helpful that they are never distinguished in any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Both this slots are (universal) PCIe M.2.
Theoretically, both of them are compatible [with SSD of such kind], but to make sure it is better to rearrange the working SSD from one to the other and check if it will work (detected by the system)